# Different Solution for handling zero in CSV Exporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Iam Exporting my datas to .csv format from asp.net project. When iam exporting those numbers having zero at beginning was handled by adding

```
="0183"
```

Then it is visible as 0183 in excel.
But the problem is when i am copying these things to other files it again copied as  ="0183"

So , can anyone help me to handle zero started numbers in export to .csv from C# coding?

Comment: could you rephrase the question again? whats the significance of `0183`?

Comment: would you please show us your code?

Comment: tried any of these? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12071963/17447

Comment: @naveen : thats just a number starts with zero. this link also explains the same what i mentioned above.

Comment: @BOBINJOSEPH, so the problem is that numbers starting with leading zeros are treated as numbers. and you want them to be treated as string, right? read http://stackoverflow.com/q/7437662/17447 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/17016803/17447 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6627301/17447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that its the excel thats auto converting the csv to string. If you create a simple CSV and open it in excel using the Open with Excel you can see the behavior. So first and easier option will be making the column type `text` and viewing it.

The other option will be to parse the column using regex before re-translating it to another format like this.

```
var inputString = "=\"0813\"";
var match = Regex.Match(inputString, "=\"([^\"]*)\"");
var output = match.Groups.Count > 1 ? match.Groups[1].Value : inputString;
```